# Exporting Gridview to PDF using ITextSharp with formatting

Tags: c#, gridview, itext

I am trying to export a beautifully designed gridview to pdf using itextsharp. The export works fine, but it only export the content of the cells. No Lines to show its a table, no background colour etc. Please How do i export such that it carries gridview as viewed in C#

Comment: search stack overflow tons of answers are given.

Comment: i've checked. None of them talked on formatting. Do you have any link you can share